# Python Bluetooth: Can't get android to print connected device name

Tags: android, python-3.x, bluetooth, sl4a

I'm fairly new to python SL4A and I could not find a question that helped me, so bear with me.

Here is what I'm working with so far:

```
import sl4a

UUID = ''

droid = sl4a.Android()

droid.toggleBluetoothState(True, False)
droid.bluetoothConnect(UUID)
print(droid.bluetoothGetConnectedDeviceName())
```

Here is the error that I get when I run the above code:

"java.io.IOException: Bluetooth not ready for this connID."

If I run the above code without the last line, I can see on my laptop that it's connected, but I want to see from the android's side that I can return the device name (for shits n' gigs).

What am I doing incorrectly so that I can get the android to return the device's name?

**Edit:** Please let me know if I should ask in a different manner; this is my first post, but I regularly troll this website for answers when I come to a roadblock.